# why resharper code inspection utility doesn't analyze some project usages

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I have one solution file. When I running resharper code inspection in Visual Studio - there are no problems. When I run resharper code inspection with utility inspectcode.exe from command prompt on my local machine - everything is ok too. But when my build-machine copies files of my solution from tfs and runs resharper code analysis from command prompt - there are some problems: resharper doesn't look on some projects usages, and think that some properties can be made private - I get resharper inspection problems. How to understand why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

By default, ReSharper Command Line Tools runs with SWEA (Solution Wide Error Analysis) enabled and "Property can be made private" suggestion is SWEA suggestion. You may disable SWEA on a build server by adding `/no-swea` key.